# Disambiguate a complex closure return type (foo -> _)

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire's [Result](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Result.swift) class. I've boiled `Result` down to a simple subset for presentation here.

```
public enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}

extension Result {
    /// Evaluates the specified closure when the `Result` is a failure, passing the unwrapped error as a parameter.
    public func mapError<T: Error>(_ transform: (Error) -> T) -> Result {
        switch self {
        case .failure(let error):
            return .failure(transform(error))
        case .success:
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get a call to `mapError` to compile.

I make a simple `Error` class and a couple of results:

```
class MyError: Error { }

let s: Result<Bool> = .success(true)
let f: Result<Bool> = .failure(MyError())
```

Now I have something to call `mapError` on! Maybe I'll print any error before passing it along unchanged:

```
f.mapError() { 
    print($0)
    return $0
}
```

Here Swift tells me "error: unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate". It doesn't seem that complex to me; `mapError` passes an `Error` into the closure, and expects one (or `T:Error`) returned, but I try placating Swift anyway:

```
f.mapError() { (e: Error)->Error in
    print(e)
    return e
}
```

Now Swift says, "error: cannot convert value of type '(Error) -> Error' to expected argument type '(Error) -> _'".

What is this `_` return type? And how should I be writing the closure?

(I realize I can avoid calling `mapError`, but whatever, I can’t seem to call it. If I really wanted to, how would I even do so?)

Comment: `mapError` wants you to return a concrete-typed instance of an `Error` conforming type; not an instance typed as `Error` itself as [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) (`Error` is not a type that conforms to `Error` and therefore cannot satisfy the generic placeholder `T` where `T : Error`). Whether or not `mapError` *should* impose this restriction is another question; I personally don't see why it should, in most cases errors are things that should be relatively weakly typed IMO (i.e just typed as `Error`). So I would just make it non-generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a closure of type `(Error) -> Error` to `mapError`
because [a protocol does not conform to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/1187415), i.e. `Error` is not
a valid `T` for the constraint `<T: Error>`.

Making `mapError` non-generic

```
public func mapError(_ transform: (Error) -> Error) -> Result
```

makes both of your usage examples compile.

Answer (score 0):

> What is this `_` return type [in the error]?

This means the compiler cannot determine a type, which might give a further clue as to what's going on...